# ntheorem in beamer has a problem with <alert@> -commands

Tags: beamer, itemize, ntheorem

Consider the following (hopefully) minimal code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\PassOptionsToPackage{ngerman}{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{thmmarks}{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
  \let\th@plain\relax
  \let\openbox\relax
  \let\proofname\relax
  \let\proof\relax
  \let\endproof\relax
  \def\@ptsize{0}
\makeatother

\usepackage{
    amsfonts,
    amsmath,
    amssymb,
    %amsthm,
    ntheorem, %% ich MUSS ntheorem laden, da ich \newtheorem brauche
    tikz,
}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{Folie I.}
    \begin{block}{Block I}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Hier ein \alert{Alert Befehl} --- seht ihr! Es klappt.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Block II}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<alert@1>
            Hier ein Alert Befehl mit \alert{at-Zeichen}
                --- warum, sobald ich ntheorem lade, funktioniert es auf einmal nicht??
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As soon as I load `ntheorem` commands like `<alert@1>` result in errors:

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{altenv} on input line 43 ended by \end{itemize}
```

ze}.

How do I circumvent these? Is this unavoidable? I really need `ntheorem` instead of `amstheorem`, since I have a load of commands of the form `\newtheorem{…}`.

My only thoughts are, to try to find an alternative way of using `<alert@>`-like commands. But I would really like to be able to use the usual beamer commands.

**UPDATE:** I realise, one *can* use `\newtheorem` using just `amsthm`. One just cannot set `\theoremstyle`, etc. But that is not too big a deal, I guess.

Comment: Beamer handles theorems in a wastly different way, I would not be surprised if `ntheorem` is labelled incompatible with beamer.

Comment: What package should I then use, in order to define custom theorem-environments?

Comment: Define custom? In beamer almost all theorems are a king of block structure and can be configured using the methods beamer provides.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `ntheorem` package in order to use `\newtheorem`. Beamer customises theorems to be like blocks and things like

```
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
```

work out of the box.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
  \let\th@plain\relax
  \let\openbox\relax
  \let\proofname\relax
  \let\proof\relax
  \let\endproof\relax
  \def\@ptsize{0}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{Folie I.}
    \begin{block}{Block I}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Hier ein \alert{Alert Befehl} --- seht ihr! Es klappt.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Block II}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<alert@1>
            Hier ein Alert Befehl mit \alert{at-Zeichen}
                --- warum, sobald ich ntheorem lade, funktioniert es auf einmal nicht??
    \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
    \begin{observation}
        bla bla
    \end{observation}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]