# How to have ntheorem with option thmarks and <alert@> beamer command working together?

Tags: beamer, environments, ntheorem

I am puzzled by the interaction between the package `\usepackage[thmarks]{ntheorem}` and the command `<alert>` from `beamer` class.

Indeed, in a recent [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574343/how-to-use-ntheorem-and-beamer-together) it has been shown that the interaction between `\usepackage[thmarks]{ntheorem}` and `beamer` class could be solved by with the option `\documentclass[notheorems, noamsthm]{beamer}`. But this previous question also emphasize the problems with the command `<alert>`.

In another [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309387/ntheorem-in-beamer-has-a-problem-with-alert-commands) the same interaction have been questioned, however the suggested solution was to not use `nthoerem`. This solution completely avoid the problem.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[notheorems, noamsthm]{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage[thmmarks, standard]{ntheorem} 

    \title{Test Presentation}
    \date{\today}
    \author{John Doe}
    \institute{Home}

\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
            \titlepage  
        \end{frame}
        
        \begin{frame}{Animation}
            \begin{itemize}[<+- | alert@+>]
                \item \alert<4>{This is\only<4>{ really} important}
                \item Now this
                \item And now this
            \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}     
        
        \begin{frame}{Theorem}
            \begin{proof}
                This is the proof with a mark at the end.
            \end{proof}
        \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

which returns the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{altenv} on input line 23 ended by \end{itemize}.
```

So, how to make `nthoerem` (with the option `thmarks`) working together with `<alert>` command (from `beamer` class) ? (Without bypassing the problem)